# Lucene: getting the full collection documents as results

Tags: java, lucene

When I perform a query in Lucene (`topDocs = searcher.search(booleanQuery, 220000);`) I get 170 hits as retrieved doc. Which is correct but I would like to have the full list of docs in the results even if the scores are very low.

Is there a way to force lucene to get the full list of documents of all my collection and not just the relevant ones ?

Or maybe it means that all other docs score is 0 ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work if you search for '*' and allow leading * in wildcard queries.
Just did a test in Luke on a 501 document index, which returns 501 results for this query.

Comment: I actually don't want to search for *, I still have my query, but I want to get all documents for results even if the scores are very low. It you can tell me that the not retrieved document have all score exactly =0 then the issue is solved. I can add them by myself on the bottom.

Comment: Update: The query would better be booleanQuery + " OR *". This way, documents matching the original query would get a higher score than the others, but the others get a score > 0 as well and thus are returned.

Comment: Example: If i look for `*beer*`, I get one document with score 1. If I look for `*beer* or *` I get all documents with the top doc having score 1.4142 and the others (that would have had score 0 in the previous query) have score 0,3536.

Comment: I've added the following lines but I still get 172 results only.  rest = new TermQuery(new Term("*","*")); booleanQuery.add(rest, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD); I've also tried new Term("title","*"); where title is an existing field, but it is the same.

Comment: I'm not sure about TermQuery Syntax, since we're build the query string manually and then use the QueryParser, e.g. QueryParser.parse("content: *beer* OR content: *");

You might need to call setAllowLeadingWildcard(true) on the query parser to allow that.

Did you add the other query terms using BooleanClause.Occur.MUST?
If so, this might prevent the other documents from being returned.

Answer (score 5):

Since Lucene 3.x, you can use `TotalHitCountCollector` to retrieve the total hits of a query. Then you can retrieve all documents for your query with the total hit count. Be careful with the case without any hits.

```
TotalHitCountCollector collector = new TotalHitCountCollector();
searcher.search(booleanQuery, collector);
topDocs = searcher.search(booleanQuery, Math.max(1, collector.getTotalHits()));
```

Answer (score 3):

please specify `q=*:*` as a search term

Answer (score 2):

This question is old now, but I think what OP was looking for is `MatchAllDocsQuery` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some field to all docs like `test:1` and then search like `[your_query] OR test:1`.

Answer (score 0):

Lucene does not do any filtering based on score. If a query has 170 hits, then it means that only 170 documents matched the query. The rest of the documents did not match and can be presumed to have a score of 0.

Comment: I see, are you sure 100% about your statement ? :) I mean, it would be perfect, problem solved.

Comment: Uhm, well I still need to include them in the final list.. is there a way to get all remaining collection docs and add them on the bottom of the list ?

Comment: Yup, I am sure this is how Lucene, or any other full-text search engine, works.

Comment: There are multiple ways of getting the remaining docs at the bottom of the list - Thomas has explained one way of getting it done in another answer to this question. Alternately, you can fire a second query which is the negative of the original query to get all the documents which did not match the original query.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question and I couldn't find a satisfactory answer anywhere. I had read that you could just use IndexSearcher.search(query, Integer.MAX_VALUE), however this seemed to be very slow so I presume memory is being allocated for the result set somewhere. I really don't know why Lucene doesn't already provide a way to get the entire result set, but here's my solution...

```
    TotalHitCollector collector = new TotalHitCollector();
    indexSearcher.search(query, collector);
    if (collector.getTotalHits() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < collector.getTotalHits(); i++) {
            Document doc = indexSearcher.doc(collector.getDoc(i));
        }
    }
```

... and the TotalHitCollector class...

```
    public static class TotalHitCollector extends SimpleCollector {

    private int base;
    private final List<Integer> docs = new ArrayList<>();

    public int getTotalHits() {
        return docs.size();
    }

    public int getDoc(int i) {
        return docs.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void collect(int doc) {
        doc += this.base;
        docs.add(doc);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doSetNextReader(LeafReaderContext context) {
        this.base = context.docBase;
    }

    @Override
    public ScoreMode scoreMode() {
        return ScoreMode.COMPLETE_NO_SCORES;
    }
}
```